Expected value of a transformed normal variable - I have the solution, how was it derived?
I have $x: X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, i.e. a normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I would like to compute $\Delta = E(f(x))-f(\mu)$, where $f(x)$ is some arbitrary function. I think that an approximation to the answer is
$$\Delta=-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\Big|_{x=\mu}$$
I did not derive this myself, this is a result I found without proof, which seems to hold based on numerical tests I ran in Python for $\sigma^2 \ll 1$. However, I need $\Delta$ for larger values of $\sigma^2$. Looking at the form, this must be based on a series expansion, but I have no clue how this was derived! I would expect that $E(f(x))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)p(x)\ dx$ where $p(x)$ is the PDF for $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, but I have no idea how to solve this integral, nor how this would relate to the second derivative of $f$.

This is from expanding $f$ in Taylor series. (Your negative sign should not be there.) Taylor expansions for the moments of functions of random variables.

Perfect, thank you!!

In fact, it comes from a mere Taylor expansion of $f$ around $\mu$.
